# Graph theory: proving that a graph with specific property is bipartite

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing, bipartite-graphs

I have been given the following problem on an exercise sheet:

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices with the property that for each $k ≤ n$, every set of $k$ vertices contains a subset of size at least $k/2$ with no edges inside it.

*Prove that $G$ is a bipartite graph.*

I am struggling to see a way to construct this proof. I have tried to use that a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd cycles, but I think I'm incorrect in doing so as I seem to be going in circles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Here is a hint: try proving the contrapositive. Let $G$ be a graph that is not bipartite. You want to show that there exists a set of $k$ vertices with no [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) subset of size at least $\frac{k}{2}$.

As you know, if $G$ is not bipartite, then there is an odd cycle, say of length $k=2m+1$. So...

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, when you say "of length $k=2m+1$", is this the same $k$ as in the statement we are trying to prove?

Comment: @mathcomp Yes. Can such a set of $k$ vertices have an independent set of size at least $\frac{k}{2}?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, this is the same $k$ if I am correct in my reasoning. So assume $G$ is **not** bipartite, but satisfies that for every $k$ there is an independent subset of vertices of at least size $k/2$. 

So take a cycle of length $k=2m+1$ in $G$. Then we need to show that having this cycle means that we arrive at a contradiction in saying that there is an independent set of size at least $k/2$. 

If we find this contradiction, then the condition on $G$ means that there can be no odd cycles and hence $G$ is bipartite. 

Now just to find the contradiction!

Comment: I can see that a cycle of length $k=2m+1$ cannot have an independent set of size at least $k/2$ because, say we partition the $k$ vertices into two sets $A,A'$, then because the odd cycle has length $k$, all vertices in $A,A'$ must be included in the cycle and for $A,A'$ to be independent subsets, there must be no edges inside them, but clearly since $k$ is odd, there must be an edge between at least two vertices in $A'$. 

I dont know if my reasoning is correct at all here, but it doesn't seem very formal :/ Sorry to keep asking :/

Comment: I am now having problems proving that an odd cycle cannot be partitioned into two independent sets (without using the fact that it is not two-colourable), which is what I think I need to prove? I'm beginning to get very confused, sorry about this

Comment: @mathcomp you can prove your result by contradiction, but it's a bit less wordy to prove the contrapositive directly. Anyway, let $S$ be a maximum independent set of vertices in an odd cycle of length $2m+1$. Then every vertex in $S$ is incident with $2$ edges. So $2|S|\leq 2m+1$, and so $|S|\leq \frac{2m+1}{2}$. Since $|S|$ is an integer, in fact, $|S|<\frac{2m+1}{2}$.